# ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddScoped called with <> instead of ()

Tags: c#

I am working through an ASP.NET Core 6 class. It has the following code:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, MockCategoryRepository>();
```

[Looking at the documentation for AddScoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), I read that as the code should be:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(ICategoryRepository), typeof(MockCategoryRepository));
```

What is going on here? (This may be due to my knowing C# 3.0 but not having paid any attention to subsequent versions.)

**Update:** As I understand it the <> is used in generics to explicitly define the type(s) used in a generic. I don't understand what it means when made part of a call to a method???

Comment: The first example is using the `AddScoped<TService,TImplementation>(IServiceCollection)`  overload, the second is using the `AddScoped(IServiceCollection, Type, Type)` overload. The angle brackets denote a [type parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters). In methods it's a way to pass a type to a method in a way that allows the method to restrict the type at compile-time and makes it easier to instantiate an instance of that type. It can also be applied to classes though to create generic types.

Comment: Keep in mind the angle brackets (`<>`) are not a replacement for parentheses (`()`) as your title suggests, they're an optional addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two are effectively equivalent in terms of function.

In C# there are two ways for a method to accept a type, either via generics or as an instance of `Type` (which is returned from `typeof()`).

The ASP dependency container accepts both.

Additionally, there are a few other overloads that you can call according to the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionserviceextensions.addscoped?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

[image]

Is there one to use over another? Not really. Microsoft documentation does not suggest the usage of one over another. I think it comes down to style in cases where it does not matter.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not following this. I added an update above and if you don't mind, can you expand on your answer? TIA

Comment: It doesn't mean anything different than the overloads @DavidThielen. The method you are calling can see the generic parameters you are calling it with the same way that it sees the formal parameters than you're calling it with.

Comment: Can you please point me to documentation about how "method<type>()" works and how it is then passed in to that method? I see that it works, but I don't understand the what/why behind it and I want to understand what is going on under the covers. TIA

Comment: @DavidThielen It is handled by `typeof` in the implementation. Look in my fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QppeKq

Comment: To further the point, here is a more complete implementation: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YQ1e4a

Comment: Ok, thank you. This was new to me - when did this get added to C#? (And if you say it was part of the initial generics implementation - very bad on me that I did not learn this back then.)

Comment: I couldn't tell you. I haven't used dotnet before core.